# Why doesn't Wildfly give my application access to org.Hornetq (HornetQ's API)?

Tags: jms, wildfly, hornetq

I really need help.

I have a simple Java Client (run by Eclipse, outside a container).
I have Wildfly 9 running on localhost.
And I have a simple MDB deployed as an ear package on Wildfly.

The Client does a JNDI lookup for "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory "
It get's and uses a HornetQJMSConnectionFactory.
It sends an ObjectMessage to the Queue that my MDB listens to.

The MDB's onMessage(Message msg) shows it receives the message.
And that msg is an instance of HornetQObjectMessage.
But when I try to cast msg to a HornetQObjectMessage, so I can retrieve the Object, it fails.

The core error seems to be NoClassDefFoundError for HornetQObjectMessage, so my application has no access to the HornetQ API (org.hornetq module I think).

Note:  The Cast is in a try catch block, but there is no output to the Wildfly log from the my catch block?

I've pasted the MDB code below.

My module.xml

And and extract of the relevant lines from the Wildfly log.
Clearly the message arrives.  See lines with "XXXXXXXXXX" prefix.
Then failure!

The ear has no war module.

Note: I added @ApplicationScoped only because it was suggested to solve an earlier problem I posted.  Is that my problem now?

Please help.

MDB CODE:

```
@MessageDriven(  
    activationConfig ={  
      @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destinationType", propertyValue="javax.jms.Queue"),  
      @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="maxSession",propertyValue="1"),  
      @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destination", propertyValue="jms/goSendToServerQueue")
    }) 

public class GoMsgBean implements MessageListener {

  @ApplicationScoped

  @Inject
  @JMSConnectionFactory ("java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory")
  private JMSContext jmsCtx;

  @Resource(name = "java:jboss/exported/jms/goSendToClientQueue")  
  private Queue sendToClientQueue; 

  public GoMsgBean () {
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void myInit () {
    System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXX Post Construct - GoMsgBean");
  }
  @PreDestroy
  public void myDestroy () {
    System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXX Post Destroy - GoMsgBean");
  }


  public void onMessage(Message msg) {
    System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXX Greetings From GoMsgBean.onMessage()");
    System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXX Message Type is " + msg.getClass().getSimpleName());
    try {
      HornetQObjectMessage oMsg = (HornetQObjectMessage) msg;
      System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXX Successfully Cast msg to HornetQObjectMessage");
      System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXX Object Type is " + oMsg.getObject().getClass().getSimpleName());
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
      System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXX ClassCastException");
    } catch (JMSException e) {
      System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXX JMSException ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXX " + e.getClass().getSimpleName()");
    }
  }
}
```

MODULE.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.acmemq">
    <dependencies>
       <!-- we depend on org.hornetq module since we will send messages to  -->
       <!-- the HornetQ server embedded in the local WildFly instance       -->
       <module name="org.hornetq" />
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

WILDFLY LOG (Extract of WARN and ERROR)

```
Calling "D:\Bulletproof\bpWildFly\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
Setting JAVA property to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: "D:\Bulletproof\bpWildFly"

  JAVA: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java"

  JAVA_OPTS: "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jbos
s.byteman"

===============================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
   ...
13:59:09,204 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make
sure it is unique.

13:59:09,880 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]

13:59:09,994 WARN  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYMSG0001: AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure
 Java NIO.
13:59:10,010 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory D:\
Bulletproof\bpWildFly\standalone\deployments
   ...
13:59:13,067 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Validator] (MSC service thread 1-8) WELD-001440: Scope type @javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped() used on i
njection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @ApplicationScoped @Inject @JMSConnectionFactory private org.america3.gotest.server.messaging.GoMsgBean.jmsCtx

13:59:13,076 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Validator] (MSC service thread 1-8) WELD-001440: Scope type @javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped() used on i
njection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @ApplicationScoped @Inject @JMSConnectionFactory private org.america3.gotest.server.messaging.GoMsgBean.jmsCtx


13:59:13,316 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 9.0.2.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.2.Final) started in 6207ms - Starte
d 480 of 676 services (264 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)

#START UP COMPLETED#
#MESSAGE RECEIVED#
14:01:04,983 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-3 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1527152166)) XXXXXXXXXX Post Construct - GoMsgBean
14:01:04,985 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-3 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1527152166)) XXXXXXXXXX Greetings From GoMsgBean.onMessage()
14:01:04,986 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-3 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1527152166)) XXXXXXXXXX Message Type is HornetQObjectMessage
14:01:04,987 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-3 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1527152166)) XXXXXXXXXX Post Destroy - GoMsgBean

14:01:04,989 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (Thread-3 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1527152166)) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component GoMsgBean for method public void org.america3.gotest.server.messaging.GoMsgBean.onMessage(javax.jms.Message):javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: WFLYEJB0457: Unexpected Error
...
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hornetq/jms/client/HornetQObjectMessage
        ...
        ... 52 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQObjectMessage from [Module "deployment.GoTest.ear.GoTest.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
        ...
        ... 80 more

14:01:05,002 ERROR [org.hornetq.ra] (Thread-3 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1527152166)) HQ154004: Failed to deliver message: javax.ejb.EJBTransactio
nRolledbackException: WFLYEJB0457: Unexpected Error
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:153)
        ...
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hornetq/jms/client/HornetQObjectMessage
...
        ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQObjectMessage from [Module "deployment.GoTest.ear.GoTest.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
...
        ... 80 more
```

Comment: HornetQ is an implementation details of the JMS API you shouldn't rely on it but use "only" the API itself. You should cast it to "ObjectMessage". By the way you may take a look at http://jmesnil.net/weblog/2012/07/27/on-jms-objectmessage-and-its-pitfalls/ before using ObjectMessage ;)

Comment: Thanks.  It seems  my client's JNDI lookup "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" produced a HornetQObjectConnectionFatory whose Session ends up sending HornetQObjectMessage to my MDB's onMessage(Message msg) method.  And trying to cast msg to ObjectMessage gave an error. Totally contra intuitive, But I've been forced from Glassfish to WildFly, so maybe something I did elsewhere to get a WildFly Connection is messing things up.  Will redo Client from scratch this week end to see if I can get a plain old ObjectMessage sent.  I'll let everyone know next week.

Comment: Maybe you have the jms.jar in your war/ear which would conflict with the one from the server.